# editText type text not showing in Android 9.0

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

Edittext type text not showing when soft keyboard is open. This happens only in Android Pie. I have researched on internet and many people say to make `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`. But when I do this, my app slows down too much.

xml code:

```
    //other views are above

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/edittext_drawable1"
                android:drawablePadding="24dp"
                android:hint="Write text..."
                android:maxLength="255"
                android:paddingStart="8dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="2dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Also, when I put the edittext more above the problem is solving. But in my case it must be at the bottom.** So how can I solve this problem?